# How do I write an assert statement for a vector in C++?

Tags: c++, vector, assert

I am creating a user class that has an ID, name, birth year, zip code, and friend's list.

I want to verify if the friend's list (which is `vector<std::size_t>`) got passed into my constructor correctly by using an `assert` statement, but I want to know if it is possible to write an `assert` statement like `assert(u->getFriends() == vector<size_t> {0, 1, 2})`

For context, `getFriends()` is a getter function that gets the `vector` of `size_t` elements of the user's friend's list.

I tried the line of code above, but I get this error message:

> macro "assert" passed 3 arguments, but takes just 1

I was wondering how I would be able to write an assert statement to find if the `vector` of the user's friend's list was correct.

Comment: Your highlighted string doesn't have a closing `)`. Please post the entire statement.

Comment: commas not in parentheses cause problems for macros -- try putting redundant parens around the expression -- `assert((`...`));`

Comment: Note the commas in `{0, 1, 2}`. That’s what the pre processor is complaining about: those commas separate arguments. To fix it, put an extra set of parentheses around the entire expression.

Answer (score 4):

Assert is a macro:

```
// https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/assert
#ifdef NDEBUG
#  define assert(condition) ((void)0)
#else
#  define assert(condition) /*implementation defined*/
#endif
```

But macros that take parameters have problems when the parameter has a comma.
So the way to pass that to a macro is to include it inside another pair of parenthesis:

```
assert((u->getFriends() == vector<size_t> {0, 1, 2}));
```

Here is a runnable example: https://onlinegdb.com/wUg-aa27T

Comment: alright thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Minor point: it’s not implementation defined. That’s a technical term in the C++ standard; it means that a conforming implementation must document what it does. A better term here would be “implementation specific”. +1.